# What strings are matched by a param in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, routes, param

If I write the route

```
get 'photos/:id'
```

What strings can be bound to `:id`? Presumably it can be expressed as a regular expression, but I can't find it documented anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you type it like that, it can be any string not containing `/` or `.`. You can override the default regex for the param using constraints key, so for example:

```
get 'photos/:id', constraints: {id: /^\d+$/}
```

will match only numbers.

Comment: I see, so my example is shorthand for `get 'photos/:id', constraints: {id: /^[^/.]+$/}`? That's clear. Thanks.